# After installing Magento 2, I can't load the magento homepage

Tags: magento, magento2

After installing Magento 2, I can't load the magento homepage as it shows the following error

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found -
>   http://local-magento2.com/setup/index.php/navigation/menu

Could someone help me to load the homepage ?

Comment: Try to checkout master branch of Magento 2 and install again and see if this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Was your Base URL correct? Did you enable .htaccess and server rewrites?

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_access-browser.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_no-styles.html

Comment: thanks@steve johnson. i had a browser gateway time error. i have solved it and installed the magento 2 successfully. thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to take a look at:

**1 - File ownership:** You have to make sure that the file ownership for the entire Magento2 install is whatever_user:server_name - for example, mine is vagrant:www-data as I am on Ubuntu on a Vagrant Box. You may need to set the ownership to **myuser:apache or myuser:nginx**

Run this on your terminal:

```
sudo chown youruser:www-data /var/www/html/
```

**2 - Users & Groups:** Make sure that the users that you are using to set the ownership are in "eachother's groups" - for me, I had to add the vagrant user in the www-data group and the www-data user in the vagrant group.

Run this on your terminal:

```
sudo usermod -a -G youruser,www-data vagrant

sudo usermod -a -G www-data,youruser www-data
```

to verify this you can run this on your terminal:

```
sudo groups youruser
```

Once you are done, restart your server like:

```
sudo service apache2 restart -or- sudo service httpd restart
```

3 - Set your file and folder permissions by running this on your terminal:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;

find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
```

4 - Enable Apache rewrite module by running this on your terminal:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

5 - Enable Apache distributed configuration by running this on your terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

go to the last line on file and add this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    AllowOverride  All
</Directory>
```

** make sure that the path to your Magento2 root folder is updated above (/var/www/html) as yours may be /var/www/magento2 or whatever you called it.

Once you are done, restart your server like:

```
sudo service apache2 restart** -or- **sudo service httpd restart
```

---

This worked for me after spending several hours trying different scenarios. Here are some links that really helped me:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html#install-update-depend-user-add2group

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-rewrites2.4

Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks for answering